# jdbc servlet is getting empty cookies (for a "keep me logged in" feature)

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, browser, jdbc

I have a jdbc servlet to handle a login page and when the user checks "remember me" the java servlet creates a cookie and stores it.

All this works so far (tested). However, when re-opening the browser and page, the very first HttpServletRequest sent to my servlet has only one cookie : the session id cookie. But after this request, the rest of the HttpServletRequests all contain the correct cookies. This is causing my initial load of the page to result in the log-in page, however if the page is refreshed, the cookies are now loaded and it logs the user in.

How I'm setting the cookie:

```
response.addCookie(new Cookie("idcookie", userid));
```

How I'm retrieving the cookies:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

I'm not really sure how cookies work, so maybe this could be a pathing issue. Anyways
This is happening to all browsers. Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe the other cookies are "session cookies" (expire when the browser is closed) or are for a different path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. It was with pathing.
Added this line to my cookie.

```
Cookie.setPath("/");
```